# Is there a way to make fusion chart's funnel display zero values?

Tags: fusioncharts

I'm using fusion charts' funnel mode to display some sums which may or may not be 0, grouped into different cathegories. I'm also displaying the number of terms that goes into each sum (for example: $1000, 3 accounts). I want the funnel to display a slice even if its value is 0 and have it displayed like $0, x accounts to give the user information on how many accounts there are in every cathegory even if the final sum is 0.

Xml for the fusioncharts object:

```
$strXML = "
    <chart showhovercap='1' showNames='1' showValues='1' numberSuffix=' lei' decimalPrecision='0' decimalSeparator=',' thousandSeparator='.' formatNumber='1' isSliced='1' slicingDistance='5' bgColor='f5f5f5'>                
      <set link='".$url1."' name='Negociere' value='".$negociere."' color='FD0006' hoverText='".$nr_negociere.$text_negociere."' />    
      <set link='".$url2."' name='Ofertare' value='".$oferta."' color='FF4100' hoverText='".$nr_oferta.$text_oferta."' />
      <set link='".$url3."' name='Analiza' value='".$analiza."' color='FF8900' hoverText='".$nr_analiza.$text_analiza."' />
      <set link='".$url4."' name='Abordare' value='".$abordare."' color='086FA1' hoverText='".$nr_abordare.$text_abordare."' />
      <set link='".$url5."' name='Prospectare' value='".$prospectare."' color='00B25C' hoverText='".$nr_prospectare.$text_prospectare."' />
    </chart>
    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by setting "streamlinedData" attribute to "0" in the  element of your XML data?

Ref. Code:

```
<chart showhovercap='1' showNames='1' showValues='1' numberSuffix='$' decimalPrecision='0' decimalSeparator=',' thousandSeparator='.' formatNumber='1' isSliced='1' slicingDistance='5' bgColor='f5f5f5' streamlinedData='0'>                
<set label="Negociere,3 accounts" value="0"/>
<set label="Ofertare, 5 accounts" value="0"/>
<set label="Analiza, 2 accounts" value="1"/>
<set label="Abordare, 1 accounts" value="0"/>
<set label="Prospectare, 2 accounts" value="0"/>
</chart>
```